# How to pass up nested state and avoid useCallback in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I have a parent and nest child component hierarchy of `QuestionsAndAnswersScreen` -> `QuestionInput` -> `QuestionSelector` -> `AnswerSelector`. I need to pass the question and answer object back up to the `QuestionAndAnswerScreen` in order to show it on the view. However I cannot find a way without going into deep nested callbacks.
Here is my code for the `QuestionAnswerScreen` and `AnswerSelector`:

```
function QuestionsAndAnswers() {
const {shell, body} = styles;

return (
    <View style={shell}>
        <SignUpHeader title="Add your answers" page={5}/>
        <View style={body}>
            {qAndA[1] ? <Answer question={qAndA[1].question} answer={qAndA[1].answer}/> : <QuestionInput />}
            {qAndA[2] ? <Answer question={qAndA[2].question} answer={qAndA[2].answer}/> : <QuestionInput />}
            {qAndA[3] ? <Answer question={qAndA[3].question} answer={qAndA[3].answer}/> : <QuestionInput />}
        </View>
        <SignUpFooter
            title={`Questions\n& Answers`}
            buttonTitle={"Done"}
            disabled={false}
            route="QuestionsAndAnswers"
        />
    </View>
    );
}
function AnswerInput(props: AnswerInputProps) {
    const {question, visible, answerModalVisible} = props;
    const {pickAnAnswer, doneButton, answerTextInput, questionStyle, shell, buttonText} = styles;
    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(visible)
    const [answer, setAnswer] = useState('');
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    useEffect(() => {
        setModalVisible(visible)
    }, [visible])

    function answerQuestion() {
        setModalVisible(false);
        navigation.navigate('QuestionsAndAnswers');
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <Modal style={shell}
                   isVisible={modalVisible}
                   onBackdropPress={() => {
                       setModalVisible(false);
                       answerModalVisible(false);
                   }}
            >
                <View>
                    <Text style={pickAnAnswer}>Add answer</Text>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <Text style={questionStyle}>{question}</Text>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <TextInput
                        style={answerTextInput}
                        placeholder="Add your answer here..."
                        placeholderTextColor="#878787"
                        onChangeText={(text: string) => setAnswer(text)}
                    />
                    <View style={{alignItems: 'flex-end', marginTop: 44}}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={doneButton} onPress={() => answerQuestion()}>
                            <Text style={buttonText}>
                                Done
                            </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        </View>
    );
}
```

As you can see I get my Question and Answer in the `AnswerInput` but then need to navigate back to the main screen in order to display them. Any help would be great thanks :)

Comment: Do you have any mind using a global store like redux? It should be really cleaner https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start

Comment: Hi, im not a fan of redux and find it can often be avoided with reworking of code. I also dont believe Im going to use this level of nesting elsewhere in my app. I have seen options for useReducer and useContext hooks but am not sure how to implement in this situation